# Node "13.0.0-nightly20190802452b393c1f" error without nightly installed

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

When trying create-react-app I get the following error.

```
Creating a new React app in /home/sabin/development/react/complete-guide.

warning You are using Node "13.0.0-nightly20190802452b393c1f" which is not supported and may encounter bugs or unexpected behavior. Yarn supports the following semver range: "^4.8.0 || ^5.7.0 || ^6.2.2 || >=8.0.0"
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.17.3
warning You are using Node "13.0.0-nightly20190802452b393c1f" which is not supported and may encounter bugs or unexpected behavior. Yarn supports the following semver range: "^4.8.0 || ^5.7.0 || ^6.2.2 || >=8.0.0"
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error @babel/core@7.5.5: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=6.9.0". Got "13.0.0-nightly20190802452b393c1f"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd /home/sabin/development/react/complete-guide has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting complete-guide/ from /home/sabin/development/react
Done.
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
node: 12.8.1

I have never installed a nightly build. I have uninstalled node from nvm and the package from the Ubuntu repo. I then installed the 12.8.1 binary from the node site. I am still getting the error, even when trying `npx -p node@12 create-react-app appname` . Any help would be appreciated.

Uninstall and reinstall of node using newest binary for linux

Comment: I found that appending --use-npm like ```npx create-react-app appname --use-npm``` fixed my problem.

Comment: Horward how did you rectify this? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 15):

The solution to this problem is simple, node has been installed from the ubuntu software library, to remove it just go there, then go to the installed software and delete node and then reinstall it via the official website.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/POn0V.png