# I want to install and run react-create-app on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, npm, npm-install

[Snap of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6jsH.png)

I tried the command `sudo npx create-react-app my-app`. It gives Node error regarding version even after I downgraded Node to LTS

I tried to downgrade Node, upgrade NPM, even clear cache of NPM. It still messes up at the Installation.
Please help me out.
Thanks.

**Edit:**

The versions I'm using are as follows:

- Node: v14.15.1
- NPM 6.14.9

and running it without `sudo` still gives the same error.

Comment: @DevangK Please [edit] such details into the question and paste the **actual** error message you are getting (as code-formatted text, not a screen-shot). "_Node error regarding version_" isn't much help.

Comment: How did you install node? Have u installed it from the Ubuntu Software Library. If so please install it from the official website. A similar issue was reported here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542067/node-13-0-0-nightly20190802452b393c1f-error-without-nightly-installed